# Проверка на $false и $true в powershell

Tags: powershell, условия

Стоит ли использовать проверку через [int] 1 и 0 булевые значения, если в условиях `If` вместо `$false` использовать 0, а вместо `$true` 1? По сути, для процессора 1 и 0 это и есть булевые значения? Или все-таки стоит переводить в булевый тип переменные со значением 0 и 1?

Пример:

```
#$a = $true
#$b = $false
$a = 1
$b = 0
if($a){write-host '$a = $true'}
else{write-host '$a = $false'}

if($b){write-host '$b = $true'}
else{write-host '$b = $false'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стоит ознакомиться с [данной статьёй на MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators/), чтобы понять, что, по большому счёту, разницы нет, - важно понимание. Теоретически, разница может быть только для ОЧЕНЬ длинных скриптов, где постоянно проверяются условия, завязанные на одни и те же булевские переменные, но и то разница будет по времени, причём, эта разница будет крайне минимальна.

Comment: спасибо, прояснило!